# Can a C# attribute add a parameter to a method?

Tags: c#, aop, custom-attributes, castle-dynamicproxy

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10217698/677526) - which is very similar to what I'm attempting. However, my use case is a little different.

We have the need to store audit history for business services. However, we need to be able to manually call audit checkpoints during method invocation, not just before and after.

We're using Castle.Core in our project. To accomplish this, I plan to create a custom attribute named `AuditContext` for use on our service methods (to audit business logic, etc.) I plan to use Castle DynamicProxy to create a logging proxy that will create a new context object based on the metadata arguments in the attribute object. What I would like to do is inject this object into my method as a method argument, but without having to specify an `AuditContext` parameter on each service method we create.

Essentially, instead of this:

```
[AuditContext(someStaticMetadata)
public BusinessObject BusinessMethod (AuditContext context, ...arguments) {
    // ...some logic...
    context.checkpoint(someAuditData);
}
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
[AuditContext(someStaticMetadata)
public BusinessObject BusinessMethod (...arguments) { // We do not have to specify the context object for every business method...
    // ...some logic...
    context.checkpoint(someAuditData); // ...but the object is still available, as the parameter has been added by the argument.
}
```

Or, to make a much more generic example, I want to write this:

```
[ProvidesParam2]
public Object myFunc (param1) { }
```

...and end up with a function with this signature:

```
public Object myFunc (param1, param2) { }
```

The distilled question is this - Can a C# attribute add a parameter to a method that it decorates, effectively changing the signature of the method at design time?

Thanks!

Comment: The only difference I see between what you're asking and the answer to the question you linked is that the `AuditContext` takes some static metadata, whereas the answer in the linked question takes an interface. Either way you have to use reflection to instantiate an object. Unless you can explain to me how what you're asking is different from the linked question, I'm inclined to vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @JimMischel The main difference between what he's doing and what I'm doing is that I'm attempting to use an attribute to change the method signature of a method. In fact, I only provided that question to show that it's not a duplicate. My use case is related to his, but the fundamental problem is different. See the code samples I provided.

Comment: The only way you're going to get `someAuditData` without passing it as a parameter is to use reflection to locate the `AuditContext` attribute, and then `Activator.CreateInstance` to instantiate it, just as the answer to the linked question says. You can't just access it as though it were a parameter.

Comment: @JimMischel If that's the case, then I wouldn't be able to access it inside my function - is that correct? The reason I'm asking about the parameters, specifically, is because I believe that I can use the dynamic proxy to pass my required object to the method at runtime. The issue is that without changing the method signature, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Yes, you can. Rather than supplying static data to the attribute, give it an object that contains a function reference. The method uses reflection to find the attribute and instantiate it, and then calls the method. The method supplies the audit context data.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Right, I understand that. Attributes, however, are also determined at design time, as it's metadata. By wondering if an attribute could "change" a method signature....I really meant that the signature would always be the same at design time, but declared through the function body and through metadata. This just may be something that C# can't do.

Comment: @JimMischel Ah, I see. That would be a lot of boilerplate for every service method, though, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @JeroenMostert A peer of mine actually mentioned Postsharp. It looks as though C# (or, possibly, the compiler) doesn't support this out of the box. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I shouldn't have posted it as a comment in the first place since it is an answer, regardless of quality. :-P Corrected that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no. Attributes do actually modify what you could interpret as the signature in special cases (like the calling convention) but they definitely cannot modify the argument list. You can achieve what you want with a custom IL rewriter; something like [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) might be able to help (disclaimer: I have no experience at all using PostSharp).